# Elastic Search: Make pretty format as the default

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to make the JSON output of `curl` commands Pretty printed by default? That is, without specifying the option of `?pretty=true` to the curl URL, is it possible to display the output pretty printed everytime?

Comment: May I suggest to have a look at the [elasticshell](https://github.com/javanna/elasticshell)? That's a lot more json friendly than curl and shows only nice prettified json objects. [This article](http://blog.trifork.com/2013/03/06/introducing-the-elasticshell/) shouldbe useful too.

Comment: Starred it. Currently learning elastic search itself so before using the elastic shell, will attempt to get comfortable with elastic search.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by adding a new alias to my .bashrc (or .bash_profile on a mac):

```
alias pp='python -mjson.tool'
```

Then, after reloading the .bashrc / .bash_profile configuration by opening a new terminal or by running

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

you can pipe curl output to the 'pp' alias as follows:

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_search | pp
```

Source: http://ruslanspivak.com/2010/10/12/pretty-print-json-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 3):

ElasticSearch has no such permanent setting and I don't want such. Quite often I see that developers forget to undo such settings in production and then overall product performance is degraded. Similar example is leaving DEBUG logging enabled which is very popular performance killer.

You have plenty of tools to ease your development:

- [RestClient‎](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/restclient/) Firefox plugin
- [ElasticSearch Head] - excellent ES admin which even pretty formats your input

plus earlier mentioned ElasticShell.

However if you really really want to make it in `curl` here is simple trick I've just made. Run this in your bash shell or script:

```
curl() { `which curl` $@ | python -mjson.tool ; }
```

And you use curl as before:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/
```

To undo:

```
unset -f curl
```

Of course it would be better to name the function as `ppcurl` if you don't like above :)

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, you use REST API from other products (JQuery, PHP, Perl, Ruby...). These frameworks don't need to have pretty input.
So, I assume that in 99% of the requests you don't want to *slow* your requests by pretty rendering JSON.

IMHO, you only need pretty print when doing debug or in dev mode.

An option could be to have it as an elasticsearch property in `elasticsearch.yml` file. [Open an issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/new) for it?

Comment: I now understand why this was not raised as an "issue" before or is not an in built functionality - as you put it, it is used inside other products and one does not directly use `curl`. I am actually attempting to learn it before using it inside my application and thus wanted to check on the console itself if my search query is returning correct results or not - its a bit annoying to specify it all the time...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use jq instead:

`curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health' | jq .`